# Feeds Import Date Repeat

Tags: feeds, datetime

I have a birthday field that has the date repeat in drupal. When i try to use feeds to import the dates using CSV, the dates get imported but i can't import the repeat date.

What is the format for the date repeat so i can import the birthday and all the repeat dates